# C# Setting variable to var using different types of System.Data.Linq.Tables

Tags: c#

I have a `var` and want to initialize it and go through a `switch case` and set the variable of the `var` but it can three different `System.Data.Linq.Tables<>`.
`dc` is a generated `DataClassesDataContext` class.

Here is the code:

```
var table = null;
switch (scope)
{
    case "LT":
        table = dc.LT_Contacts;

        break;
    case "LV":
        table = dc.LV_Contacts;

        break;
    case "SW":
        table = dc.SW_Contacts;

        break;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In general a variable has a type and you cannot change it's type at runtime. Why do you want to treat three different tables as same? What are you going to do with `table`? Also, if you have three different tables which store similar things this often indicates a mistake in the database design. Maybe you should have used one table with an additional column `ContactType`.

Answer (score 3):

`var` is not a magic thing that will make the variable have a dynamic type. Instead, it’s just a way to tell the compiler to infer the type from the right side of the assignment.

As such, `var something;` or `var something = null;` can never stand on their own because there is no way for the compiler to statically infer the type at compile-time.

You can only use `var` when the right side of the assignment has an actual type, and then `var` is equivalent to explicitly mentioning that type.

In your case, you will have to specify an explicit type, and in order to be able to compile, you need to use a type that is assignable from all three types of those data context properties. E.g. it needs to be a base-type of those table types.

In the case of [`System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx), you could use any of the non-generic interfaces it implements. Depending on your need, what you want to do with the variable afterwards, you might want to choose one over another. For example `ITable`, or `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pick the most suitable common interface or base non-generic class.

In case of `System.Data.Linq.Table<T>`, it looks like it is `ITable`:

```
ITable table;
switch (scope)
{
    case "LT":
        table = dc.LT_Contacts;
        break;

    case "LV":
        table = dc.LV_Contacts;
        break;

    case "SW":
        table = dc.SW_Contacts;
        break;

    default:
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Obviously, you will be able to work only with members of `ITable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

since there is no type bound to null,you cannot assign null to var variable. instead you can do the same as follows.

```
var x= (DataType)null;
```

Eg:- `var x= (string)null;`